# SED command to replace / alone in a line

Tags: sed

I have below text in a file. need to replace `/` to `;`:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE AAA

  /
```

please not that there is space present in front of `/`.
it needs to be converted as

```
CREATE SEQUENCE AAA

  ;
```

Comment: `sed 's:/:;:' filename`?

Answer (score 3):

You just escape the /

```
sed 's/\//;/' file
```

Add `-i` to modify the file in place

```
sed -i 's/\//;/' file
```

Or use a different separator as in [comment by Muru](https://askubuntu.com/questions/836460/sed-command-to-replace-alone-in-a-line/836466#comment1278401_836460)

Comment: it is not working since / has extra space in front.

Comment: Working here regardless of space @asalthangam what is happening for you exactly?